# How do I Analyze Crosstalk in an Unbraided Multi-Cable?

Tags: transmission-line, interference, ribbon-cable, crosstalk

Near-end crosstalk (NEXT) and far-end crosstalk (FEXT) are defined for twisted cable pairs [[1]](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/95aug/aug95a3a.pdf), while both FFT and Baum-Liu-Tesche equations have been applied to analyze crosstalk in bidirectional coaxial cables[[2]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/icp.jsp?arnumber=4106101). In contrast, I wish to simulate a model for straight unidirectional wires in a multi-lead cable.

My goal is to visualize the crosstalk and how it affects the "pure" signal. I only have access to a compound signal and not the individual leads. However, this is a broadband signal, where I can isolate the narrowband components and the momentary phase.

How can I study crosstalk in **multiple pairs** of straight wires that share direction of current, but with varying phase*?

* The phase is neither exclusively odd nor even, but is subject to continuous phase shifts. The wires belong to circuits with independent power sources.

---

**Edit: Resources**

These are the materials I am working with right now:

- [Rise time of model systems (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rise_time#Rise_time_of_model_systems)

I also found [this resource](https://books.google.de/books?id=s7vkBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA454&ots=-EAWjfmaIZ&dq=multipair%20cable%20crosstalk&pg=PA456#v=onepage&q=multipair%20cable%20crosstalk&f=false) interesting:

> "The error rate in multipair cable systems is affected by the
>   transmitted signal, level, cable loss, crosstalk, and the required
>   receiver signal-to-noise ratio."—Digital Transmission Systems, Ch.
>   7.8.

I still haven't figured out if the equation 7.25 applies though. It involves "the transfer function of the baseband code".

---

<sub>In extension to "straight", these types are also of interest:</sub>

<sub>||   parallel</sub>

<sub>\/ fanning</sub>

<sub>X crossing</sub>

<sub>> < kissing</sub>

<sub><< bending</sub>

<sub>*Question moved from physics.stacksexchange.com*</sub>

Comment: Did you google "ribbon cable crosstalk"? What results did you get and what's unsatisfactory about them. If you're using randomly bundled wire cables, and concerned about crosstalk, just don't; pick a cable type where there's some guarantee of where the return wire is relative to the signal wire.

Comment: @ThePhoton Actually, the cable is more like a fiber bundle. Thanks for the key word!. I am googling as we speak.

Answer (score 3):

Take this to a simpler level; you have a single wire carrying current and another wire close-by. There will only be an induced voltage across the ends of the close-by wire when the current in the interfering wire changes. That induced voltage is proportional to rate of change of current. The further the wires are spaced the lower the interference.

If that rate of change of current occupies part of the spectrum that the close-by wire doesn't use (or protects itself against) then the problem is usually significantly less.

The interference voltage across the ends of the wire will be somewhat attenuated by the impedance of the driving circuit being low and the receiving impedance being low. At either end, if the impedance is high then maximum potential interference will be seen (irrespective of it being in band or out of band).

If the signal travelling down the close-by wire is digital in nature then the amount of interference received by that wire may make very little effect to the effectiveness of its own transmission.

Now the other side of the story - capacitive coupling. Interference happens due to rate of change of voltages on one cable inducing current flow into the other cable (capacitively coupled).

As mentioned before this is mitigated by the two wires occupying different parts of the bandwidth.

This dv/dt scenario is also mitigated by the close-by wire using a low impedance signalling/communication system.

So, in short, you need to consider: -

- Magnetic field interference
- Electric field interference
- Distance between wires
- Spectral occupancy of the two wires
- Impedances used on the close-by wires

Bring a bunch of cables together and the problem does become sizable.

---

### Extras

For anything other than the very basic shapes the biot savart law is the fundamental mathematical building block for understanding the magnetic flux at a given point in space projected from a complex shaped current carrying conductor: -

[image]

As you should be able to see, for complex shapes of wire, the math equally becomes complex. So, say you manage to do the math (on a really easy scenario like a single turn coil), you will get the total flux density at one point in space. Say you have a "receiving" coil of wire at some distance away then you have to integrate the magnetic field (at point P) in two directions in the plane of that second coil to the boundary of the circumference.

This gives you the total flux entering the centre region of that coil. *This section was edited/corrected due to me getting things wrong*!!

Then you have a simple formula i.e. Induced voltage = N\$\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ that tells you the induced voltage based on rate of change of flux. For a simple single turn loop (as per a wire) N = number of turns = 1.

However, life is not made easier when current (due to that induced voltage) is drawn along that recive loop due to it forming a circuit i.e. a load is connected. This "extra" current reduces the local magnetic field around the receiver loop and therefore reduces the original induced voltage. Added to this is cross interference from other conductors and it starts to look a bit like a University post-grad thesis in level of complication.

This is why most folk will use a PC and FEA (finite element analysis) software.

You could go down a totally different route and calculate the mutual inductance between wires with the assumption that a cable is largely staight and has largely constant gaps between conductors: -

[image]

Once you have the mutual inductance (for this simplified model) you can get to an approximate solution fairly quickly using a voltage transformer model. This is probably the route that I'd take.

I'm going to put a halt to my answer now but bear in mind I've only discussed magnetic fields in this "extra bit". However, for capacitive coupling you can make some fairly simple models and come up with the capacitance between conductors.

All (every bit of my answer) assumes that the length of the wire and the highest frequency involved in the analysis do not cause transmission line theory to be invoked. I'm not going to even go there - you have the key words!

Comment: Great description. What equations and axioms do I need to make predictions about the system?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I study crosstalk in a pair of straight wires that share direction of current, but with varying phase*?

You can estimate the mutual inductance between an aggressor loop (signal wire + return wire) and a victim loop (signal wire + return wire). Given that and the current signal risetimes and amplitudes you can easily calculate the crosstalk effect on the victime wire.

If the two loops share the same return path, you should also consider IR drops on the return path due to the aggressor signal as a crosstalk on the victim channel.

**Edit** As Andy points out, there is also capacitive (electric field) coupling to consider. AFAIK, this is rarely the dominant source of crosstalk in the type of cables you seem to be asking about, although it could become an issue if the cable and/or its terminations are badly designed.

> In extension to "straight", these types are also of interest...

Parallel wires is going to be the worst case scenario. All of your other scenarios are going to have lower crosstalk than a parallel pair separated by the smallest amount of separation in a non-parallel pair.

Wires crossing at 90 degrees will have the least  crosstalk.

Comment: I think your first answer-paragraph should make a better distinction between mutual inductive coupling (di/dt) and capacitive coupling (dv/dt).

Comment: I am completely new to this field, so apologies for asking basic questions. I think I should be able to estimate the parameters, but I am more concerned about what equations/software library to use. Say, if I have an absurd amount of cables, then I would have multiple aggressor loops. Is there an equation that generalizes for multiple leads or do I simply compute all possible permutations?

Comment: You're not going to get very useful analytical results for randomly arranged round wire cables.  Consider the worst case scenario: two wires strictly parallel as close together as the insulation allows. If the results for that case are not acceptable, choose a different cable technology.

Comment: In my particular case, I cannot make any changes to the system. I just want to figure out when it is not working due to cross-talk. It's very old technology...

Comment: Then you'll need to do measurements rather than analysis.